# vbscript insert array into access database

Tags: sql, csv, vbscript, ms-access-2010

I have a simple task with a complex procedure. I'm creating a tracking program that tracks the usage of applications, as well as other pertinent info. I'm first recording the data from the application in a temporary text file that will be deleted once the data is retrieved. The data is separated by commas so that it can be stored in a CSV file. This CSV file will be used to quickly pull specific pieces of information for review. The data will also be stored permanently in a 2010 Access database. I've been able to store the data in the text file. I've been able to create a VBScript to read the data from the text file and copy it to the CSV file. What I need to do is figure out why, when I've put a message box above the script that inserts the data to the database, I can see the info in the message box, but it won't print to the database and I'm not receiving any error messages.

Here's the VBScript code:

```
' Set constants for reading, writing, and appending files
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8

' Sets up the object variables.
Dim objExcel, objFSO, objTextFile, objCSVFile, objTrackingFolder

' Sets up the integer variables.
Dim intPathYPos

' Sets up the all the string variables for the program.
Dim Desktop, todaysDate, usageDate, myDay, myMonth, myYear, UserIDPath, myMessage
Dim strTextFile, strHeadLine, strTextLine, strCSVFile, UserID, strTrackingFolder, strConnect, strSQL, strSplitData, testDisplay
Dim message

'This creates the required Objects
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Desktop = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%") & "\" & "Desktop"
UserIDPath = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")

'------------------Calls up the Process Tracking Submission sub-------------------

call ProcessTrackingSubmission

sub ProcessTrackingSubmission()

intPathYPos = InStr(4,UserIDPath,"\")
intPathYPos = intPathYPos + 1
UserID = Mid(UserIDPath, intPathYPos, 10)

'msgbox(RTrim(UserID))
'exit sub

' Set date for date stamp in file name and sheet name
todaysDate = Date()

myMonth = Month(todaysDate)
If Len(myMonth)=1 Then myMonth="0" & myMonth

myDay = Day(todaysDate)
If Len(myDay)=1 Then myDay="0" & myDay

myYear = Right(Year(todaysDate), 2)

usageDate = myMonth & myDay & myYear

' Set up the origin and destination files
strTextFile = Desktop & "\MacroTracker.txt"
strTrackingFolder = "E:\My Storage Files\" & UserID
strCSVFile = strTrackingFolder & "\TrackingTesting" & usageDate & ".csv"
strHeadLine = "App Name,User ID,Ran At,Data 1,Data 2,Data 3,Data 4,Data 5,Data 6,Data 7,Data 8"

Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strTextFile)

Wscript.Sleep 600

' Read the entire origin file
Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    strTextLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
Loop

Wscript.Sleep 600

objTextFile.Close

If (objFSO.FolderExists(strTrackingFolder)) Then
    If (objFSO.FileExists(strCSVFile)) Then
        ' Create object for appending current TXT file to CSV file
        Set objCSVFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strCSVFile, ForAppending, True)
    Else
        ' Create CSV file to write to with today's date
        Set objCSVFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strCSVFile, True)
        Wscript.Sleep 1000
        ' Write initial header for the CSV file
        objCSVFile.WriteLine strHeadLine
    End If
Else
    Set objTrackingFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strTrackingFolder)
    If (objFSO.FileExists(strCSVFile)) Then
        ' Create object for appending current TXT file to CSV file
        Set objCSVFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strCSVFile, ForAppending, True)
    Else
        ' Create CSV file to write to with today's date
        Set objCSVFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strCSVFile, True)
        Wscript.Sleep 1000
        ' Write initial header for the CSV file
        objCSVFile.WriteLine strHeadLine
    End If
End If

' Write an append line of data to the CSV file
objCSVFile.WriteLine strTextLine

 Wscript.Sleep 600

strDataLine = Split(strTextLine, ",")
strAppName = strDataLine(0)
strUserID = strDataLine(1)
strRanAt = strDataLine(2)
strData1 = strDataLine(3)
strData2 = strDataLine(4)
strData3 = strDataLine(5)
strData4 = strDataLine(6)
strData5 = strDataLine(7)
strData6 = strDataLine(8)
strData7 = strDataLine(9)
strData8 = strDataLine(10)

' Connect to the database
strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\My Storage Files\Tracking Apps.mdb"
conn.Open strConnect

Wscript.Sleep 600

' Write data to table
    if strAppName = "Hello Application - version 1" Then
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Macro Tracking] ([App Name], [User ID], [Ran At], [Data 2], [Data 6]) VALUES ([" & strAppName & "], [" & strUserID & "], [" & strRanAt & "], [" & strData2 & "], [" & strData6 & "])"
    end if

Wscript.Sleep 600

objCSVFile.Close
conn.Close

' Wait for file to be written to
Wscript.Sleep 600

' Delete origin file to prevent user tampering
objFSO.DeleteFile(strTextFile)

end sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've worked with HTML databases, so I have an idea of what the SQL should look like, but I've never wrote one in VBScript and everything I've found on the Internet doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what [roland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17971172/1630171) already pointed out, VBScript does not expand variables inside strings. `strSplitData(0)` in `"... VALUES (strSplitData(0), ...)"` is just the literal string `"strSplitData(0)"`, not the value of the first field of the array `strSplitData`. You could build the query string by concatenation like this:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Macro Tracking] " & _
         "([App Name], [User ID], [Ran At], [Data 1], [Data 2], " & _
         "[Data 3], [Data 4], [Data 5], [Data 6], [Data 7], [Data 8]) " & _
         "VALUES (" & _
         strSplitData(0) & ", " & _
         strSplitData(1) & ", " & _
         strSplitData(2) & ", " & _
         strSplitData(3) & ", " & _
         strSplitData(4) & ", " & _
         strSplitData(5) & ", " & _
         strSplitData(6) & ", " & _
         strSplitData(7) & ", " & _
         strSplitData(8) & ", " & _
         strSplitData(9) & ", " & _
         strSplitData(10) & ")"
```

However, doing this is [not a good idea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), so just forget I mentioned it. Better use a [parameterized query](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200190) (AKA prepared statement) instead:

```vbs
db = "E:\My Storage Files\TrackingApps.mdb"
strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & db & _
             ";User Id=admin;Password=;"

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open strConnect

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Macro Tracking] ([App Name], [User ID], " & _
  "[Ran At], [Data 1], [Data 2], [Data 3], [Data 4], [Data 5], [Data 6], " & _
  "[Data 7], [Data 8]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

Set p1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@p1", 3, 1, 0, 0)
cmd.Parameters("@p1") = strSplitData(0)
cmd.Parameters.Append p1

Set p2 = cmd.CreateParameter("@p2", 3, 1, 0, 0)
cmd.Parameters("@p2") = strSplitData(1)
cmd.Parameters.Append p2

...

Set p11 = cmd.CreateParameter("@p11", 3, 1, 0, 0)
cmd.Parameters("@p11") = strSplitData(10)
cmd.Parameters.Append p11

cmd.Execute
```

Adjust the arguments of the [`CreateParameter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677209) calls as needed.

Comment: Ansgar, I tried what you said and it's saying I can't use this because of the provider I'm using. I'm using `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`...I would need to use `Microsoft.Office.12.0.Access.Database.Engine`, then recreate the database as Access 2010 doesn't allow you to change file types once you create a database (if it does, I haven't figured it out and already destroyed a .accdb database just to create a .mdb)

Comment: I tested it with an Access 97 DB and the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` provider (using the connection string from [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)), and it worked just fine. Please update your question with the exact error message you're getting, and the line that raises the error.

Comment: The WSH error that I'm getting is on line 24: `Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn`. The error code is `800A0E7D`, the source is `ADODB.Command`, and the error is `Requested operation requires and OLE DB Session object, which is not supported by the current provider`. I added everything you sent above. The line for `conn` is `Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")`. I even made sure everything has been Dim'd.

Comment: @Lou You need to `Open` the connection first.

Comment: I have `conn.Open strConnect`, which is immediately after where I define `strConnect` with the provider and the path to the database. Should I change it to `cmd.Open strConnect` seeing as `conn` is consumed when setting `cmd`?

Comment: @Lou I updated my example with code for opening the connection.

Comment: Ok...I have that. Now, I'm receiving a different error: `Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation.` The code is `800A0D5D`, and it's happening on the line `cmd.Parameters("@p1") = strSplitData(0)`. Is it because `strSplitData(0)` is an array? I need this to accept an array of data from a CSV or comma delimited text document.

Comment: Like I already said: adjust the parameter type as needed. The parameter type must match what the database expects for that particular field.

Comment: What does "adjust parameters as needed" mean? What parameters should I adjust and how should I adjust them?

Comment: `cmd.CreateParameter(...)` creates a parameter of a particular type. My example is using type 3 (`adInteger`) for all parameters, but that may not match the actual type of the fields in your database, so you probably need to change it.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting the hang out of `CreateParameter()`, but now I'm faced with a different issue. This one program runs off of several others. It is called when the first program is done. Each program sends different data, but the VBScript is designed to accept data from every program. I have one line that is set up to input currency, `Set p5 = cmd.CreateParameter("@p5", 6, 1, 7)`, but I'm getting the error `Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation.` I'm guessing because I'm not sending a $$ at the moment. Any suggestions?

Comment: The answers didn't help. It seems as though it's HOW I'm sending the data in the `INSERT INTO` line. I've seen instances on the internet where strings get added as `'" & myString & "'`, dates and times get entered as `#" & myDateTime & "#`, etc. I believe the issue is how I'm inserting the currency. I have it formatted in my database as "currency", but even with setting the parameter for currency, I still have issues. Is there a good site where I can see the different formats as I explained in the beginning for `'" & myString & "'`?

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714540).

Comment: That didn't have anything on what to use with the variables within the `INSERT INTO`. I found that I was having issues with the data in the variables containing special characters, so I needed to format the variables in the `INSERT INTO` string as such `[" & myString & "]`. Now I'm getting the `80040E10` error saying "No value given for one or more required parameters.", yet for every A, there's an A, for every B, there's a B...so every parameter has a value.

Answer (score 2):

You define strSQL, but don't execute the SQL statement, add

```
conn.Execute strSQL
```

after the `strSQL = ...` line

Comment: Ok...just tried that, but now I'm receiving the following WScript Host error:

'Script: C:\Tracking App.vbs'
'Line: 114'
'Char: 2'
'Error: Command text was not set for the command object.'
'Code: 80040E0C'
'Source: Microsoft JET Database Engine'

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Add square brackets to the table and column name containing spaces: `[Macro Tracking]` `[App Name]` `[User ID]`...

Comment: Still receiving the same error message. Do I need to remove the commas and parenthesis? Line 114 is the `strSQL = ...`, so it's something wrong with that line.